# Symfony Webpack encore error on run. encore: Permission denied

Tags: symfony, npm, webpack, yarnpkg, webpack-encore

Symfony 4.1 with webpack encore gives error on run with npm/yarn

I followed the steps mentioned in official documentation of symfony, after successfully installing via `composer require webpack-encore` and after `npm install`, I tried `npm run dev` and got below error, same permission denied occurs when using `yarn encore dev`.

I'm using debian 9

```
kamii@kamii-workstation:~$ node -v
v10.9.0
kamii@kamii-workstation:~$ npm -v
6.4.1
kamii@kamii-workstation:~$ yarn -v
1.9.4
```

VIA NPM:

```
kamii@kamii-workstation:/media/disks/Development/dev_lab_gen/exim_pos$ npm run dev

> @ dev /media/disks/Development/dev_lab_gen/exim_pos
> encore dev

sh: 1: encore: Permission denied
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! @ dev: `encore dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/kamii/.npm/_logs/2018-09-03T20_11_01_530Z-debug.log
```

Via Yarn

```
kamii@kamii-workstation:/media/disks/Development/dev_lab_gen/exim_pos$ yarn encore dev
yarn run v1.9.4
$ /media/disks/Development/dev_lab_gen/exim_pos/node_modules/.bin/encore dev
/bin/sh: 1: /media/disks/Development/dev_lab_gen/exim_pos/node_modules/.bin/encore: Permission denied
error Command failed with exit code 126.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Here is the NPM log file

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'dev' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.9.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle @~predev: @
6 info lifecycle @~dev: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~dev: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/media/disks/Development/dev_lab_gen/exim_pos/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
9 verbose lifecycle @~dev: CWD: /media/disks/Development/dev_lab_gen/exim_pos
10 silly lifecycle @~dev: Args: [ '-c', 'encore dev' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~dev: Returned: code: 126  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: @ dev: `encore dev`
13 verbose stack Exit status 126
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:250:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd /media/disks/Development/dev_lab_gen/exim_pos
16 verbose Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v10.9.0
19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 126
22 error @ dev: `encore dev`
22 error Exit status 126
23 error Failed at the @ dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 126, true ]
```

Comment: Try with "./node_modules/.bin/encore dev-server"

Comment: @joseFG Ohh I didn't think of that. `node ./node_modules/.bin/encore dev` worked. Can you please explain why it is not working with npm/yarn?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was on a partition mounted with `noexec` flag by default. Adding `exec` flag explicitly in `/etc/fstab` solved my problem, even solved some other permission issues with `gulp`.

> User mounted partitions, e.g. when using the ‘user’ or ‘users’ mount options in the /etc/fstab file, are done with the ‘noexec’ mount option by default for security reasons. This means that memory mapping (mmap) files for execution will be denied. Another reason can be the lack of kernel support for shared writable mmap which was added to Linux kernel 2.6.26.
>
> Solution: Add the ‘exec’ mount option to the end of the mount options. It’s important that the option to be the last one, otherwise other mount option can over judge its effect. However please also note that Wine was not designed to run arbitrary applications directly from a Windows partition. To do so, one must install the Windows application via Wine onto the Windows partition first.

Answer (score 4):

In my case removing node_modules folder and running `yarn install` helped. My directory permissions changed and it influenced locally installed encore.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
`./node_modules/.bin/encore dev-server`

If so, you probably have the encore installed globally and therefore when you run it you do not have permission to do it in the global folder.

Write `echo $PATH` and check if encore is here.

Comment: The stated command does not run and returns same "Permission denied" error. Although `node ./node_modules/.bin/encore dev` is working perfectly fine. Encore is not installed globally as I've never installed it explicitly, it was installed locally in the project during the initial setup of Symfony webpack-encore.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to lean on @Jose's comment and share some common pitfalls:

When installing `encore` did you put `-g` (for global) flag? If not, that could be the reason.

Another common thing is that your `encore` was indeed installed globally (possibly `/usr/local/bin`) but you OS does not see it. This could merely be due to bad `$PATH`. Try to run `source ~/.bash_profile` and then retry. If you still cannot run it, the path is probably not included in your `$PATH`.

Finally, I hit this one pretty hard some months ago with fresh installation of Centos, where `node` persistently failed to install anything globally. Tutorials on Google will tell you just to `chmod 777` your `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`, which is just plain bad idea. Instead, configure your `node` to use different destination path for its modules.

Hope this helps a bit...

Comment: I thought about that exactly =)